# Showing a previously hidden bootstrap alert

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

This is a simple Bootstrap alert:

```
<div id="alert_recover_ok" class="alert alert-success hidden">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&#x2716;</a>
    Please check your email for recovery instructions
</div>
```

As you can see, it is hidden (*by classname*). Now I'm trying to show it:

```
$('#alert_recover_ok').fadeIn();
```

Nothing happens... The only solution that seems to be working is:

```
$('#alert_recover_ok').removeClass('hidden');
```

...but of course, that won't have the nice fade in effect. Any ideas?

Comment: tried something like `$('#alert_recover_ok').hide().removeClass('hidden').faseIn();`? jQuery might be clearing the hidden class correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own `hidden` class.

The bootstrap `.hidden` class is as follows, which is why just `.fadeIn();` wont work...

```
.hidden {
    display: none!important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
}
```

So you can create your own `hidden` class.

```
.hide-me{
    display: none;
}
```

Use this instead of `hidden` and then the `.fadeIn();` will work.

[DEMO](http://bootply.com/107259)

Comment: Note: in more recent versions of `bootstrap.css`, the `hidden` rule no longer includes the `visibility` property.  So it should be safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because fadeIn() doesn't remove your class, which continues to hide the element.

This is a kludge, but it should work:

```
$('#alert_recover_ok').removeClass('hidden').hide().fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove **.hidden** class from bootstrap css and write your own custom hidden class like following ..

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```